# fatal error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory

Tags: fatal-error, arduino-ide, esp32

I'm trying to make a "home weight" with my ESP32 and display the value using IBMCloud, however I'm running into some issues with the Arduino IDE and my code.

I get this error:

> Arduino:1.8.5 (Windows 10), Tarjeta:"ESP32 Dev Module, QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, None"
>
> C:\Users\XX\Documents\Arduino\IBM_Watson_Connect\IBM_Watson_Connect.ino:8:25: fatal error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> exit status 1
> Compiling error for the ESP32 Dev Module card.

I'm using a ESP32 dev board. My code is this:

```
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    #include <PubSubClient.h> // https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/releases/tag/v2.3

    #include "HX711.h" //Load Cell Amplifier
    HX711 cell(D2, D4); //Amplifier is connected to these pins on the NodeMCU ESP8266 Board

    #define WLAN_SSID       "XXXXX"  
    #define WLAN_PASS       "XXXXX"  

    #define ORG "XXXXX"
    #define DEVICE_TYPE "XXXXXX"
    #define DEVICE_ID "XXXXX"
    #define TOKEN "XXXXXXXX"

    char server[] = ORG ".messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com";
    char topic[] = "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json";
    char authMethod[] = "use-token-auth";
    char token[] = TOKEN;
    char clientId[] = "d:" ORG ":" DEVICE_TYPE ":" DEVICE_ID;

    WiFiClient wifiClient;
    PubSubClient client(server, 1883, NULL, wifiClient);

    void setup() {


     Serial.begin(115200);
     Serial.println();

      // Connect to WiFi access point.
      Serial.println(); Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Connecting to ");
      Serial.println(WLAN_SSID);

      WiFi.begin(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS);
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
      Serial.println();

      Serial.println("WiFi connected");
      Serial.println("IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    }

    int counter = 0;

    void loop() {

     if (!!!client.connected()) {
     Serial.print("Reconnecting client to ");
     Serial.println(server);
     while (!!!client.connect(clientId, authMethod, token)) {
     Serial.print(".");
     delay(500);
     }
     Serial.println();
     }


    //----------Get data from load cell and amplifier

      long valCalibrated = 0;
      long val = 0;
      float count = 0;


      count = count + 1;
      val = 0.5 * val    +   0.5 * cell.read();
      valCalibrated =  (val - 4137240) / 234.20;

    //----------Send data to IBM Waton IoT Service

     String payload = "{\"d\":{\"weight\":";
     payload += valCalibrated;
     payload += "}}";

     Serial.print("Sending payload: ");
     Serial.println(payload);

     if (client.publish(topic, (char*) payload.c_str())) {
     Serial.println("Publish ok");
     } else {
     Serial.println("Publish failed");
     }

     ++counter;
     delay(100); //adjust delay to send more or less reads per unit time
    }
```

Some places mentioned that the library was missing, that the board wasn't properly selected, the library wasn't updated.. I checked them all.. Arduino is updated, libraries are installed and updated, proper board is selected (I actually have tried all the other Esp32 related boards with the same result)

Comment: Sure I did. Some places mentioned that the library was missing, that the board wasn't properly selected, the library wasn't updated.. I checked them all.. Arduino is updated, libraries are installed and updated, proper board is selected (I actually have tried all the other Esp32 related boards with the same result).. So yes, I've searched long before posting the question here :-)

Comment: Why do you think an ESP8266 specific library should work on an ESP32?

Comment: @Thonka glad to hear. Updating your question with this information may help others to avoid suggesting things you already have tried (what not yet happened).

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the post. :-)

Comment: @gre_gor I've tried (WiFi.h) with the Wifi library from Espressif, but the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're building a program for the ESP32, not the ESP8266. There are a lot of similarities but they're entirely different chips with different software.

So you don't use ESP8266WiFi.h with the ESP32. On the ESP32, the header file is just called WiFi.h (keeping more in line with WiFi support on Arduinos - the ESP32 Arduino Core is intended to be more compatible with the normal Arduino Core than the ESP8266 version was).

You need to

```
#include <WiFi.h>
```

instead of ESP8266WiFi.h

You can find the code for these files in [the official repository for the Arduino SDK for the ESP32](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32).

(It doesn't help that [WiFi.h for the ESP32](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFi.h) identifies itself as ESP8266.h in its own comments...)

Comment: I did try that, but the error then it's this: Multiple libraries for "WiFi.h" were found
Used: C: \ Users \ XX \ Documents \ Arduino \ hardware \ espressif \ esp32 \ libraries \ WiFi
  Not used: C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Arduino \ libraries \ WiFi
exit status 1

Comment: That means you have more than one library installed which provides a WiFi.h file. Did you install any other libraries in the Arduino IDE? You'll need to go to "Include Library" under Sketch, then "Manage Libraries" and find the library which has WiFi.h and then remove it. You need to use the one that's included with the ESP32 framework.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've double checked that there are not more than one WiFi.h file in the libraries, I've even complete uninstall Arduino IDE and install it from 0, added only the ESP32 library.. but the same error appears.. "Multiple libraries for "WiFi.h"

Comment: And if you don't add the ESP32 library?

Comment: I tried building with <WiFi.h> on my copy of the Arduino IDE and it builds fine. You need to get rid of the library that has the duplicate WiFi.h in it. Just re-installing the Arduino IDE would probably not do that. Try exiting it, then remove the Documents\Arduino\libraries folder. Then start the IDE again and try building your program with WiFi.h again.

Comment: I've tried the code with WiFi.h in another laptop where only Arduino was installed (not the ESP32 or any other library/hardware) and the result is different: 
/Users/thony/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IBM_Watson_Connect/IBM_Watson_Connect.ino: In function 'void setup()':
/Users/thony/Documents/Arduino/libraries/IBM_Watson_Connect/IBM_Watson_Connect.ino:47:34: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   WiFi.begin(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS);
                                  ^
exit status 1
'D2' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Then, I've added the ESP32 and the multiple libraries for WiFi.h error has appeared again alongside the error above

Comment: Yeah don't add the ESP32 library. You shouldn't need it. It's redefining things that are already defined, which is stopping your program from properly building. The other error that you're seeing about D2 not defined is because you took code that was meant for an ESP8266 and just tried to compile it without updating it for an ESP32. D2 is defined for certain Wemos D1 ESP8266 boards. Not for ESP32s. You'll need to identify the pin number you need for your ESP32 board and replace D2 with it. But just for fun change D2 to 5 and see if your project builds. Put the correct pin number in later.

Comment: You'll also need to replace D4 with the correct pin number as well.

Comment: Followed your advice, I tried the code with the WiFi.h, deleted the espressif folder in hardware and libraries, changed the D2, D4 for 2, 4 and gave me error "espressif package unknown", I copied back the espressif to the hardware folder and voila! it's compiled without error. :-) Thanks @John Romkey!